# How to use com.android.calendar.DayView?

Tags: android

I need a calender control in my application to show some "appointments" in a day view. As far as I see it, there are two ways: Write my own control which would be not that funny and to use `com.android.calendar`.

Can anyone tell me how I can use [`com.android.calendar.DayView`](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#b2bXTFUfX1o/src/com/android/calendar/DayView.java&q=%22package%20com.android.calendar%22&d=4) or whether at all it is possible. One important thing: I do **not** want to show the appointments of the user but rather my own dynamical added ones.

I am talking about this control: [image]

Just for information: I am aware that there are some similar questions on SO. However, I'm interested in `com.adnroid.calendar.*` and not as a general question :-).

Comment: have you done this calendar day view?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That class is not in the SDK. It is undocumented. It is unsupported.

However, it *is* open source. You are welcome to copy it into your own project (and refactor it into your own package), but you will be on your own to figure out how to make it work.

FWIW, there is a similarly undocumented/unsupported/open source widget in the [Google I|O 2011 app](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/).

It is possible that there are other open source implementations of this sort of widget that are documented and supported, though I can't think of any. I will probably take one of these and use it as the basis for a documented/supported widget someday, if nobody beats me to it.

Comment: Thank you already for the link to the Google I|O app. I'il check it out. I'm just not that into "designing" my own widget because of lack of expertise. So I've a look if I can build my own on top of those code lines...

Comment: Ok. As far as I see it this is the only answer that is possible at the current point. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I really wanted to be able to re-use DayView, so I created the [yadview](http://code.google.com/p/yadview/) project (https://code.google.com/p/yadview/). yadview is a fork of the DayView schedule in the AOSP Calendar app, but has been reworked significantly to allow for integration into any application.

Sample screenshot of an Activity with this View:
[image]

Comment: How do I limit the number of pages.I want to show daily events on a page for the past seven days.How do I limit that using YadView?The pages keep swiping infinitely.Please help.