# How to fill list rows with colors according to requirement?

Tags: android, listview

I want to show current day events so for that i have [used this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6858162/custom-calendar-dayview-in-android)to create the following view [image]. Now i would like to show my events on that view and i want to fill that particular scheduled time with color. can any one help me to do this.I don't have onclickListener i need to show the events on the scheduled time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use getView() of list Adapter.

In that method you can set condition for filling respective rows. That's It.

For your reference [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217753/changing-background-color-of-listview-items-on-android) solution provided by @ubzack

Comment: i want to set the color of the row according to the event to particular time not for all as background.

Comment: Have u created a layout for a single row of list in xml and inflating it?

Comment: could you pls check my question in that i have provided the code link.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0; i&ltparent.getChildCount(); i++)
```

{
     if(i == position)
     {
               parent.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
     }
     else
     {
               parent.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
     }
 }

Comment: One more thing you an try is set default Backgroundcolor to the view. And then set another background color according to your condition.

Comment: i don't have onclickListener in my activity i need to show the events on my view which i'll get from server that i need to show in my view.

Comment: Here it is giving Childcount as 0.

Comment: @Jitu: Instead of posting a new answer, you should have posted it as an Edit to your previous post. :)