# Daily Calendar/Weekly Calendar View in Android studio

Tags: java, android, calendar

I am currently developing a calendar app on Android Studio.
I would like to display my events on the calendar similar to the way as the Google calendar app. (Shown as below)
It is my first time developing calendar app on Android Studio so I am not sure how I could render the UI in terms of Android Layout and Views.

Please could anyone point me to the direction how I could create the UI?
(e.g., Which Layout/View should I use?)
I have done some research on the layouts of Android studio and I guess the calendar is kind of made with one the following Layout:

1. Table Layout
2. Grid Layout
3. Android Canvas

I am planning to implement similar behaviour to the events(Appointment blocks) on the calendar similar to Google's (which I could click on the blocks and manage the appointments).

It would be great if anyone could also point me to where I could find sample code for it.

My SDK info is as below:

> Android Studio --> 4.0.1

> App target OS version --> API 27:Android 8.1 Oreo

> Language --> Java

[image: Daily Calendar]
[image: 3days/Weekly Calendar]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom calendar dayview in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6858162/custom-calendar-dayview-in-android)